# m4v file won't play in safari browser on IOS

Tags: ios, iis-7, m4v

I'm trying to have a `.m4v` file play as a failover since IOS still won't allow Flash. I can play the `.m4v` file on Windows through a few browsers, but even if I go directly to the `.m4v` file on my server from an iPad it won't play. All I see is a black screen.

I have the debug console open and I don't receive any messages or see any content.

I deployed the `.m4v` file on my personal web server and can play it from there. The MIME type is correctly set.

This is the MIME type:

```
.m4v = video/x-m4v
```

What else could be wrongly set?

Here is an example of my HTML:

```
<video id="movie" width="320" height="240" preload controls>
    <source src="/SurroundHealth/videos/sample_ipod.m4v" />
    </object>
    <div class="fallback">
       <p>You must have an HTML5 capable browser.</p>
    </div>
</video>
```

Here is the url:

> http://dev.surroundhealth.net/surroundhealth/videos/test.html

Comment: **I deployed the .m4v file on my personal web server and can play it from there** - what type of server? Cassini, IIS, IIS Express, Apache or other? You're saying it will or won't play on the iPad from your personal server?

Comment: It is IIS7 - I forgot to add that

Comment: So it doesn't play on IOS through IIS7... but it does play from my co-workers personal web server. I made sure that the MIME types were the same as his... but no dice. It does work in chrome, but not IOS... which is what i need

Comment: Please don't add back in sigs, they're disallowed on Stack Overflow [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured this out, so we put the video on youtube

Answer (score 1):

Modify the MIME type to read application/octet-stream instead of video/mp4 - worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I think your mime type is incorrect and it should be:

`.m4v = video/mp4`

References:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14

Comment: I changed the MIME type but it still doesn't work :( Do you have any other suggestions? This is my first time posting to stackoverflow - thank you for letting me know about signatures